# FATAL: 58P01: could not open directory "/opt/homebrew/lib/postgresql@14": No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql

After I install the PostgreSQL 14 using brew commnad in macOS 13.2 with M1 chip, then I want to start the PostgreSQL using this command:

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@14/14.6_1/bin/postgres -c config_file=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@14/14.6_1/postgresql.conf -D /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@14
```

show the error like this:

```
FATAL:  58P01: could not open directory "/opt/homebrew/lib/postgresql@14": No such file or directory
HINT:  This may indicate an incomplete PostgreSQL installation, or that the file "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@14/14.6_1/bin/postgres" has been moved away from its proper location.
LOCATION:  getInstallationPaths, postmaster.c:1518
```

is that the PostgreSQL did not support the M1 chip? Is it possible to run PostgreSQL 14 in my machine? what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In `/opt/homebrew/var/log/postgresql@14.log` (found via `/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@14/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@14.plist`) I see:

```
postgres: could not access directory "/opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@14": No such file or directory
Run initdb or pg_basebackup to initialize a PostgreSQL data directory.
```

Doing what it suggests:

```
$ initdb /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@14
```

allows the service to start successfully.